# NotePad++ Regular Expression and Replace

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

How can i replace

```
$lang['abc'] with lang('abc')
```

and

```
{$lang['abc']} with ".lang('abc')."
```

including quotes.

Where i am stuck is how RegExp can save `'abc'` to be used in replaced text

Comment: Use a backreference. I'm sure that notepad++ help contains examples.

Comment: backreference like what, what's in php for example

Comment: Yes.  A capture group that is backreferenced by saying `\1` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First one** (tested in N++):

Search: `\$lang\['(abc)'\]`

Replace: `lang\('$1'\)`

**Second one** (also tested in N++):

Search: `\{\$lang\['(abc)'\]\}`

Replace: `".lang\('$1'\)."`

The back reference mentioned by devnull is the content of the (abc) parentheses. The parentheses capture abc into Group 1. That content is referred to in the replacement as "$1". You may like to read [all about regex capture](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html).

Comment: @Wasim It works in my N++. In the Replace tab, are you sure you checked the "Regular Expression" box at the bottom left?

Comment: @Wasim You're welcome, I'm glad. Please see edit explaining the backreference.